# Rails app cannot find 'destroy_user_session_path' in javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a rails app that has been migrated over the years starting at 2.2 to 3.2.  I am using Devise, and Omniauth to get logins working, unfortunately I think during migration I have messed something up.

When I try to setup the session delete in application.html.erb I get the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `destroy_user_session_path' for #<#<Class:0xb468e278>:0xb423e1dc>
```

application.html.erb:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Coffee Tracker</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application'%>
  <!--%= stylesheet_link_tag 'scaffold' %-->
</head>
<!--%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %-->
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
...snip...
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <span id="currentuser"><%= current_user.email %></span>
  <%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => 'delete') %>
<% else %>
```

I also get the same error when I try the line:

```
 <%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %>
```

application.js

```
// Place your application-specific JavaScript functions and classes here
// This file is automatically included by javascript_include_tag :defaults
//= require_self
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Rails 3.2.0
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i686-linux]

- rails (3.2.0)
- jquery-rails (2.0.0)
- devise (2.0.0)
- omniauth (1.0.2)
- omniauth-facebook (1.2.0)
- omniauth-oauth2 (1.0.0)

**Update:**
Here is the rake routes:

```
user_omniauth_callback     /users/auth/:action/callback(.:format) users/omniauth_callbacks#(?-mix:facebook)
           coffee_list GET /coffee/list(.:format)                 coffee#list
                  root     /                                      menu#index
                           /:controller(/:action(/:id(.:format))) :controller#:action
```

Comment: if you do any change to your `routes.rb`file, you have to restart the webserver to see the changes.

Comment: Can you do a rake routes and post the sections relating to user sessions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was missing the the database authenticatable devise module which adds the route.

app/models/user.rb:

```
 devise :omniauthable, :database_authenticatable
```

rake routes:

```
      new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)               devise/sessions#new
          user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)               devise/sessions#create
  destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)              devise/sessions#destroy
user_omniauth_callback        /users/auth/:action/callback(.:format) users/omniauth_callbacks#(?-mix:facebook)
           coffee_list GET    /coffee/list(.:format)                 coffee#list
                  root        /                                      menu#index
                              /:controller(/:action(/:id(.:format))) :controller#:action
```

I found documentation to confirm that shows the modules that use authenticatable  create these routes in the devise_for documentation: http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper#devise_for-instance_method

Comment: are your users also authenticating against the local database (as opposed to the omniauth methods)? I am working with a similar setup, and I do not need all the [extra functionality that database_authenticatable adds](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb) to the model.  I wonder if just manually adding a route would be preferable?

`delete '/users/auth/sign_out', :to => 'users/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session`

Comment: Yes actually. I had them initially able to login locally or via omniauth.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to use `omniauthable` without `database_authenticatable`, you'll need to add the route manually.

In `routes.rb`:

```
devise_scope :user do
  delete "/users/sign_out" => "devise/sessions#destroy"
end
```

Then in your view:

```
= link_to "Sign out", users_sign_out_path, :method => :delete
```

For more info, see these Omniauth Facebook and Twitter tutorials:

- [https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3a-Overview)
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-devise-and-omniauth-revised

Why must we do this?  See Jose Valim's rationale here:

- https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1840

Comment: No problem :)  I'm glad someone else could benefit from my struggles

Answer (score 2):

You have two solutions either to:

1. Add the :method => :delete to the link_to
2. Or, in the devise.rb file change the line config.sign_out_via =
   :delete to config.sign_out_via = :get

Comment: Sorry there was a typo in the question, I did try the :method => :delete and it still failed.

Comment: Did you try config.sign_out_via = :get in the devise.rb file?

Comment: Yes it didn't work because I wasn't using an authenticatable model (ie. database_authenticatable in my model) which adds the route.

Answer (score 1):

```
user_session_path(current_user), :method => :delete
```

Is my recommendation unless you have a specific named route of "destroy"

Comment: Is destroy_user_session_path supposed to be a route then?  I guess part of my problem is that I don't know where/how it is supposed to be generated so I am not sure where to even look in fixing it.